# Why is my two way data binding not working in ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, data-binding

While working on a project in ionic i noticed my two data-binding bugging out.
I really can't get my head around why this is the case.

I tried making a new ionic project with "ionic start myApp sidemenu" to test out the data binding, and even in the new project it is not working. Am i the one doing something wrong or is this just really bugging out?

[Link to the working databinding example i'm following](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/controller/)
As you can see in that example, when you fill in the input fields: first name, last name AND full name gets update. When i add this code to an ionic project, only the first/last name get updated, but the full name doesn't get updated and stay on the values initialized in the controller.
It look likes the $scope.firstName and $scope.lastName don't get 'live updated' in the controller but only in the view for some reason.
If i try to console log the $scope.firstName after i filled in the input field, it still returns 'john' (the initial value) and not the value i filled in.

Code in ionic:

html

```
<ion-view view-title="Search">
  <ion-content>
    <strong>First name:</strong> {{firstName}}<br />
    <strong>Last name:</strong> <span ng-bind="lastName"></span><br />
    <strong>Full name:</strong> {{getFullName()}}<br />
    <br />
    <label>Set the first name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/></label><br />
    <label>Set the last name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"/></label>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope) {

  // Initialize the model variables
  $scope.firstName = "John";
  $scope.lastName = "Doe";

  // Define utility functions
  $scope.getFullName = function ()
  {
    return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
  };

})
```

routing:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.search', {
    url: '/search',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-bind. From AngularDocs

> The ngBind attribute tells AngularJS to replace the text content of
>   the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and
>   to update the text content when the value of that expression changes

replace

```
<strong>Full name:</strong> {{getFullName()}}<br />
```

with

```
<strong>Full name:</strong> <span ng-bind="getFullName()"></span><br />
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It's still not applying the 2 way binding

Comment: The link that you give is seems working. There must be something wrong with the ng-model.

Comment: Yes in the example link it working, but when i copy this code in my own ionic project, it doesn't bind the getFullName. In the example link, if you fill in the fields, the full name also updates. when i do this in my ionic project. It doesn't

Comment: You can try wrap firstname/lastname in  an object. For eg: obj.firstname/obj.lastname and don't forget to initialise it as $scope.obj = {}